# MS Access 2013 initiate screencapture tool, save image as jpg, add directly into attachment field

Tags: ms-access, field, attachment, screen-capture

While I am on a form, in a record, in the attachment field I would like to automate the following steps from within Access:

1. Screen capture of other applications (desktop, websites, etc.)
2. Add screen capture image files directly into the active record's attachment field

I am trying to avoid having to save the scree capture to a file location and having to browse to add it to the active attachment field.

Comment: Just save screenshot to temporary file using API function, add this file as attachment using VBA, no need to browse, all automatic. Then delete temp table.